# How to retrieve brand and model info by code on Android?

Tags: android, exception, build, model, permissions

There is an class **android.os.Build** that got static variables cointaining device info,
but when i try to access it I allways get a runtime exception.

E.x on how I try to access it:

```
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

I always get an Exception like this:

```
04-14 14:57:45.266: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.VerifyError: com.mypackage.Main
```

I cant find any info about needing any special security permission on this.

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Build.MODEL` has been there since the beginning. You should not get a `VerifyError` from accessing that public static data member. There are a couple of ones on `Build` that are newer (e.g., `CPU_ABI`) and therefore will give you a `VerifyError` if you are trying to access them on older devices/emulators -- the documentation indicates in which API levels the various data members were introduced.